# Calling helper method with controller's method as parameter

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, helper

I'm trying to call a method (clickRegister) from a Helper class:

```
  class AdminPanelHelper {
  constructor() {

  }
  static clickRegister(callback){
    var promise = new Promise(function(res,rej) {
      $('.register-link').click(function() {
        $('.admin-body').fadeOut(function() {
          callback();
          res();
        })
      });
    })
    promise.then(function() {
      $('.admin-body').fadeIn();
    })
  }
}
```

at my controller:

```
class AdminPanelController {

  constructor() {
    this._loginView = new LoginView($('.admin-body'));
    this._registerView = new RegisterView($('.admin-body'));
  }

  showLogin(){
    this._loginView.update();
    var e = this;
    AdminPanelHelper.clickRegister(e._registerView.update);
  }

}
```

But I'm getting on the console the error 'View.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_element' of undefined'

I'm using the mvc design partner with the RegisterView extending View.
Really don't know what is wrong, the element was declared at "this._registerView = new RegisterView($('.admin-body'));"

EDIT:

Adding RegisterView class and View Class:

```
class RegisterView extends View {
  constructor(element) {
    super(element);
  }

  template(){
      return `
      <div class="form-body">
      <div class="welcome">
        <h2 class="login-welcome">This is only for test, your account will be deleted after 20min</h2>
      </div>
        <form id="register" class="" action="register" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="" placeholder="USER">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="EMAIL">
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="PASSWORD">
          <input type="password" name="passwordConf" id="passwordConf" value="" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD">
          <input class="btn btn-primary register-user" type="submit" value="Register" id='regsubmit'>
        </form>
        <div class="register-link-body">
          <span>Back to <a class="login-link">login</a></span><br>
        </div>
        </div>
      `
  }
}
```

View Class:

```
class View {
  constructor(element) {
    this._element = element;
  }

  update(model){
    this._element.html(this.template(model));
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your code snippet is missing some code? Where is the markup (HTML) that accompanies your JavaScript? Do elements with the classes '.register-link' and '.admin-body' exist in your markup?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to create a class in JavaScript just to have a static helper method. Just use a plain old function.

Comment: If I use only this._registerView.update(), it will update to the register view, but if its like to the question the error appears. I'm doing this just to train MVC model, doing dynamic pages.

Comment: Try this `AdminPanelHelper.clickRegister(this._registerView.update.bind(this))`;

Comment: Actually, not sure about that. Can you provide the code for your RegisterView class?

Comment: About the bind(this), didn't work:/, I've solved for now adding the template() as a parameter and using the .html() inside the helper method e._adminHelper.clickRegister(e._registerView.template(),e._loginView.template()); But would be nice to know why didn't worked before and how it could work. Well, already provide the RegisterView. Btw thank you for your helping.

Comment: Most welcome. Is this some particular JavaScript framework or view library? Or is this just an MVC pattern you are following with your classes?

Comment: Just MVC pattern